# xampp mysql slow after bind 0.0.0.0

Tags: mysql

Need to access xampp mysql database remotely for replication but when I do bind 0.0.0.0 it just slows the database down completely, can anyone shed some light?

thanks :)

Comment: Slows down...what?  The initial connection?  Something else?  Did changing it back make any difference?

Comment: Why are you binding to 0.0.0.0?  Shouldn't you be connecting to the real IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by connecting the database via 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost, thanks all!